# Is there a way to relay bluetooth between phones?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a device that can only be controlled by bluetooth on a specific phone. Would it be possible to use a second phone to act as a relay or proxy close enough to connect via bluetooth to the device, but kind of feign the connection with the first phone over the network?

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to make a mesh network.
https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/introducing-bluetooth-mesh-networking/